# Scrapy: CrawlSpider Rules process_links vs process_request vs download middleware

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

This is less of a "how do I use these?" and more of "when/why would I use these?" type question.

**EDIT: This question is a near duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553117/how-to-filter-duplicate-requests-based-on-url-in-scrapy), which suggests the use a Download Middleware to filter such requests. Updated my question below to reflect that.**

In the [Scrapy CrawlSpider documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html), rules accept two callables, `process_links` and `process_request` (documentation quoted below for easier reference).

By default Scrapy is filtering duplicated URLs, but I'm looking to do additional filtering of requests because I get duplicates of pages that have multiple *distinct* URLs linking to them. Things like,

```
URL1 = "http://example.com/somePage.php?id=XYZ&otherParam=fluffyKittens"
URL2 = "http://example.com/somePage.php?id=XYZ&otherParam=scruffyPuppies"
```

However, these URLs will have a similar element in the query string - shown above it is the `id`.

I'm thinking it would make sense to use the `process_links` callable of my spider to filter out duplicate requests.

**Questions:**

1. Is there some reason why `process_request` would be better suite to this task?
2. If not, can you provide an example of when `process_request` would be more applicable?
3. Is a download middleware more appropriate than either `process_links` or `process_request`?  If so, can you provide an example of when `process_links` or `process_request` would be a better solution?

**Documentation quote:**

> process_links is a callable, or a string (in which case a method from
>   the spider object with that name will be used) which will be called
>   for each list of links extracted from each response using the
>   specified link_extractor. This is mainly used for filtering purposes.
>
> process_request is a callable, or a string (in which case a method
>   from the spider object with that name will be used) which will be
>   called with every request extracted by this rule, and must return a
>   request or None (to filter out the request).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. No, `process_links` is your better option here are as you are just filtering urls and will save the overhead of having to create the `Request` in `process_request` just to discard it.
2. `process_request` is useful if you want to massage the `Request` a little before you send it off, say if you want to add a `meta` argument or perhaps add or remove headers.
3. you don't need any middleware in your case because the functionality you need is built directly into the `Rule`.  If `process_links` were not built into the rules, then you would need to create your own middleware.

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive answer, it is much appreciated!