# Avoid Duplicate URL Crawling

Tags: scrapy

I coded a simple crawler.
In the settings.py file, by referring to scrapy documentation, I used

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter'
```

If I stop the crawler and restart the crawler again, it is scraping the duplicate urls again.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me whether you had to import a corresponding package? I added the `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` to my settings.py file, but got the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.dupefilter'`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is "persistence support", to pause and resume crawls.

To enable it you can do:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

You can read more about it [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html).

Answer (score 8):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class), `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` is already set to `scrapy.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter` by default.

`RFPDupeFilter` doesn't help if you stop the crawler - it only works while actual crawling, helps you to avoid scraping duplicate urls.

It looks like you need to create your own, custom filter based on `RFPDupeFilter`, like it was done here: [how to filter duplicate requests based on url in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553117/how-to-filter-duplicate-requests-based-on-url-in-scrapy). If you want your filter to work between scrapy crawl sessions, you should keep the list of crawled urls somewhere in the database, or csv file.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite Scheduler with Redis like [scrapy-redis](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis) then you can **avoid duplicate URL crawling** when reruning your project.