# Would Scrapy re request same URL if encountered in different domain?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Imagine I have `dont_filter = False` and for current domain it will not send duplicate requests for already encountered URLs,  but lets say I move to a different domain, will it send a new request?

Actually I just want to log URL's that have duplicate requests along with their referrer. What should be the appropriate place to capture these duplicate requests?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Requests are already being filtered and logged, set `DUPEFILTER_DEBUG=True` on settings to check those logs.

You could also create your own `dupefilter` implementation, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660552/avoid-duplicate-url-crawling).

There you could check the referers with on the Requests headers:

```
request.headers.get('referer')
```

Comment: I'm aware of duplicates being logged but where can I log(or use, sepertely) these URLs if I want to do something with those URLs?

Comment: on your own dupefilter implementation.