# python exceptions.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_settingI

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy 0.2 with python2.7

I want to know if the links, which i am scraping on now, have been scraped before.

I searched a lot and I found this example [how to filter duplicate requests based on url in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553117/how-to-filter-duplicate-requests-based-on-url-in-scrapy)

I copied the code and put it in my spider folder and changed the setting but I got this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1237, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1099, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 66, in start
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self._spider, self._start_requests())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1237, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1099, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 221, in open_spider
    scheduler = self.scheduler_cls.from_crawler(self.crawler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\core\scheduler.py", line 25, in from_crawler
    dupefilter = dupefilter_cls.from_settings(settings)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'from_settings'
```

my code:

```
import os

from scrapy.dupefilter import RFPDupeFilter
from scrapy.utils.request import request_fingerprint

class CustomFilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    def __getid(self, url):
        mm = url.split("&refer")[0] #or something like that
        return mm

    def request_seen(self, request):
        print "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"
        fp = self.__getid(request.url)
        if fp in self.fingerprints:
            return True
        self.fingerprints.add(fp)
        if self.file:
            self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
```

and in the setting i added this:

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'myproject.spiders.CustomFilter'
```

Comment: Post your code here. Show us what you did.

Comment: @Bibhas thanks for your comment. I posted my code

Comment: Do you happen to have a file named `dupefilter_cls.py` in your python path?

Comment: @damienfrancois no i don't have that file in my python folder. However, I have these files `dupefilter.py`, `dupefilter.pyc`, `test_dupefilter.py`, and `test_dupefilter.pyc` in my python folder, which is `c:\python27`