# Scraping Unique Website With Scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to scrape a website and using Scrapy to recursively get all URLs under a domain.
I used HtmlXPathSelector

```
hxs.select('//a/@href').extract()
```

to get URLs.

However, I got lots of URLs are very similar to each other.
Is there any way to consider these URLs as one website ?

Example:
http://infohawk.uiowa.edu:80/F/YY75HHTMTKKDNCBT7JBYQBH64VAFXIDNMS1YT4MRKSVF5A53HK-21930?func=myshelf-short&folder=BASKET&folder_key=BASKET&sort_option=04---A

http://infohawk.uiowa.edu:80/F/YY75HHTMTKKDNCBT7JBYQBH64VAFXIDNMS1YT4MRKSVF5A53HK-09565?func=myshelf-short&folder=BASKET&folder_key=BASKET&sort_option=04---A

I got about 80000 such different URLs, so I am wondering if I have done something wrong ? 
Other URLs are like :

`53HK-39000`
`53HK-20000`

My algorithms are like :

```
for cur in url_lst:
    if cur in visited:
         continue
    yield Request(cur, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: If you want to filter them accross all parsed sites, [write a custom middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553117/how-to-filter-duplicate-requests-based-on-url-in-scrapy).

Comment: How are you getting your url_lst? Scrapy will not revisit URLs queued by Request(). This is controlled by the `dont_filter` parameter in `Request()` which is False by default. ie don't don't filter == filter. Slightly unfortunate choice of negative logic, simply calling it do_filter would have been nicer imho.

Comment: do you want to get only one item from a set of pages?